# Is there a tool or website that can form paragraphs or sentences from specific words?

Tags: discussion

I'm learning new vocabulary and I thought it would be helpful if there's a tool to take specific words as input and form a meaningful paragraph from them.

Comment: [*Have you ever written a work and wanted to use a word you do not know exactly how to use? Then you have found the right place. "Foboko sentence dictionary"](https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/)is a service that gives you examples of how to use a word. We can also help you find out what it means, find inflections of the word as well as synonyms.* Here's an example with the word "sink" https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/sink

Comment: For collocations there's this website https://ozdic.com/collocation/sink and here's a site that also gives examples of famous quotes using the selected word https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=sink%20%2Fs%3Af&findid=-1&ff=&ffo=true&l=0&t=0

Comment: You may also want to ask this question on [languagelearning.se] or [ell.se] since they are more populated with people specifically concerned with language learning tools.